# Assign a string to a given "bucket" based on its value, and keep bucket size approximately equal

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, google-apps-script

I'm not sure if this question is too vague for this format, but I'll try to be specific.

I am adding product information to a Google Apps Script ScriptDB which stores things as JSON objects. Due to unreliable behavior when there are too many objects or objects that are too large, I believe I have to store them like this:

```
{
    "bucket": "AB",
    "data": {
        "AB8000": {
            "price": 25.99,
            "qty": 29,
            "tstamp": 1358861169691,
        },
        "AB0900": {
            "price": 24.99,
            "qty": 0,
            "tstamp": 1358861169691,
        }
    }
}
```

There are about 25,000 products and I need an algorithm that will take the SKU (AB8000 for example) as a parameter and return a bucket to assign that SKU to.

My problem is that the distribution of SKUs is uneven. Using the first two characters ("AB") didn't work because some buckets would have 2,500 members and some buckets would have 5. 
The best I've been able to do is (SKU[3] + SKU[5]) which yields (obviously) 100 buckets, and the largest has about 600 members. 600 members seems to be approximately the magic number where problems start arising.

Is there a math or maybe a hashing function I can run on the SKU that will reliably distribute them somewhat evenly? 
I don't need the buckets to all be exactly the same size, but ideally there would be no more than about 400 in the largest one, and somewhere between 50-100 total buckets.

-- Edit:

I am trying a function like this right now:

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sku.length; i++) {
  sum = sum + sku.charCodeAt(i);
}

var bucket = sum % M; // M is bucket size

return bucket;
```

But this does not distribute them evenly either. When I use a value of 100 for 'M' I get a distribution of:
`1 1 1 1 4 7 12 9 19 31 38 61 91 107 151 152 184 216 249 290 317 335 362 392 446 511 513 571 574 604 657 680 680 697 716 703 698 687 701 677 672 683 679 655 671 662 640 629 651 623 596 556 532 485 425 384 314 245 204 163 125 91 59 39 27 19 11 11 10 6 6`

When I use a value of 60 for 'M' I get:

`677 672 683 679 655 671 662 640 629 651 623 596 556 532 485 425 384 314 245 204 163 125 91 59 40 31 26 23 20 29 37 44 63 92 107 151 152 184 217 250 290 317 336 363 392 446 511 513 571 574 604 657 680 679 697 716 703 698 687`

Comment: You could just sum the characters of the strings. I don't understand the notion of a storage service that makes the client do that sort of work however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much *any* hashing scheme would do that.  As the commenter suggests, added up the characters and then do `% 100` to pick a bucket.

Comment: I edited my question right before you answered. I tried that approach and it doesn't seem to work, might be missing something fundamental.

Comment: Interesting phenomenon.  Try multiplying `sum` by 7 after each addition.

Comment: Ended up multiplying sum by i+1 and that seems to work nicely. 200-300 items per bucket.

Comment: I wouldn't use that factor.  If the lengths of your sku's tend to be 1 less than a divisor of `M`, you'll get a lumpy distribution.  Better to use a factor known to be prime relative to `M`.

Comment: Thanks. That does result in a somewhat better distribution.